# Opencv : How to get the coordinates of two circle center?

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have a little problem and i want some help. I have a image with two circles and i want to get the coordinates of the centers. For one circle i solved the problem. I don't know hot to get the second one circle. Any ideas?

Here is my code :

```
Mat canny_output;
      vector<vector<Point>> contours;
      vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

      Canny(BGRFilter,canny_output,100,200,3);

      findContours(canny_output,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,Point(0,0));

      vector<Moments> mu(contours.size());

      for (int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
      {
          mu[i]=moments(contours[i],false);
      }

      vector<Point2f> mc(contours.size());

      for (int i=0;i<contours.size();i++)
      {
          mc[i]=Point2f(mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00,mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00);
      }



      Mat drawing = Mat::zeros( canny_output.size(), CV_8UC3 );

      for( int i = 0; i< contours.size(); i++ )
      {
          Scalar color = Scalar( 121, 100, 90 );
          drawContours( drawing, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );
          circle( drawing, mc[i], 4, color, -1, 8, 0 );
      }
```

Here is the binary image
[image: Here os the binary image]
Here is the image with the contours.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Hough Circles](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/imgtrans/hough_circle/hough_circle.html) for finding circles.

Answer (score 0):

if hough Circles not find circle

try [minAreaRect](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minarearect) or [minEnclosingCircle](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#minenclosingcircle)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it with Hough circle detection. Thanks.